# how to add search functionality above the table by using datatables 1.9.4

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using datatables inbuilt search but for large data it is taking time to appear search text box, i want to implement search text box above the table so that it comes early than the table.

code:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                     "bStateSave": false,
                     "iDisplayLength": 100,
                     "deferRender": true,
                     "sDom": '<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
                     aoColumnDefs: [
                                    {
                                       bSortable: false,
                                       aTargets: [ -1,-2 ]
                                    }
                                  ]
            } );
```

Comment: I don't understand - the search box is taking a long time to appear?

Comment: there is a timegap between table and search text box to appear...both should appear at once..for less data it is appearing at a time but for more data it is taking time..

Comment: Is this when the page first loads, or when searching?

Comment: When I have used datatables, I'm sure the table and controls render first, then the data is populated - is this not the case for you? Also, until the data has loaded, the user isn't going to be able to search anyway, so an extra textbox may not help.  Can you post your datatable initialisation code?